# What is the brightest star (relative magnitude) in M31?

Tags: star, apparent-magnitude, magnitude, hypergiants, m31

I am wondering what the brightest individual star is in M31, the Andromeda Galaxy.  Specifically, brightest as seen from Earth (so relative magnitude).

Comment: I assume you're discounting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SN_1885A a supernova in M31 in the year 1885?

Comment: Yes, I am discounting supernovae.  I am specifically wondering about stars Gaia could look at (so, ideally will be visible over a 5 year period).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Variable stars that Hubble studied in M31 when he showed that it was a galaxy are among the most luminous. They include Var-A1, a luminous blue variable, and [magnitude about 16.5](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.6859.pdf). Var A-1 is one of the most luminous stars known.

Nasa has a [catalog of stars](http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/W3Browse/star-catalog/m31stars.html) in the m31 field, The brightest star in this catalog is an [11.4 magnitude](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=%401560657&Name=TYC%202788-276-1&submit=submit) star. But I think that database needs careful interpretation.